# SOAP Message with RESTful web services

Tags: web-services, web

I am sending a SOAPMessage with some data in its SOAPBody in which one xml tag is binary64 encoded file. (not a SOAP wilth Attachments). The file can be more than 20MB size(and encoding it is 1.33 larger than the original size). I am sending this SOAP message to a RESTful web service in a HttpEntity object. Is there any way I can compress or optimize the size of this SOAPMessage. I have already checked that MTOM is not suitable for RESTful web services and XOP i am not sure. Please help me out how can optimise this message before sending to RESTful web service.

Comment: Getting rid of the SOAP part...?

Answer (score 0):

You can .zip file before conversion do base64